# How to run JavaScript code Monday to Friday with JQ

Tags: jquery

Looking for a simple jQuery code which would schedule JavaScript code (JavaScript for Pure Chat). The JavaScript code is supposed to be run Mo - Fri, 9 - 5:30 GMT.

So it should be something like:

```
JQ function (mo - fr, 9 - 5:30) {

    js window.purechatApi etc 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below javascript code to determine the current day. The getDay() function return numeric value from 0 to 6 which are the days from Sunday to Saturday respectively. You have to add the

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay(); 
if(n >=1 && n<=5)
{
    // 1 for monday and 5 for friday
    // your code to check date and time
    var currentD = new Date();
    var startChat = new Date();
    startChat.setHours(9,00,0); // 9.00 am
    var endChat = new Date();
    endChat.setHours(17,30,0); // 5.30 pm

    if(currentD >= startChat && currentD < endChat ){
        console.log("yes!");
    }else{
        console.log("chat off");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer! This is exactly what I was after!! Many thanks!! The only concern I have - if the user is in a different time zone, the chat room still should be only visible 9 - 5 UK time.